GoogleMaps custom markers clustering performance issue
I have performance issues with moving, zooming map with custom markers clusters.
I tried using best practices: avoid re-render, batch, debounce clusters, all loading and resizing tasks made asynchronous and all ui updates in main thread, but still have lags and snooze map performance.
If anyone has any tips, I'd appreciate it.
This is MarkerPostItem.swift:
class MarkerPostItem: NSObject, GMUClusterItem {
    var position: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var post: PhotoPost
    var image: PFFileObject
    var imageUrl: URL?
    var uiImage: BehaviorRelay<UIImage?> = .init(value: nil)
    
    private let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    private let imageLoader: ImageLoaderProtocol = ImageLoader()
    
    init(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D, post: PhotoPost, image: PFFileObject) {
        self.position = position
        self.post = post
        self.image = image
        self.imageUrl = URL(string: image.url ?? "")
        super.init()
        self.fetchAndResizeImage()
    }
    
    private func fetchAndResizeImage() {
        imageLoader.loadImage(from: imageUrl, placeholder: UIImage(named: "google-icon")) { [weak self] image in
            let resizedImage = image?.resizeImage(to: 150.0)
            self?.uiImage.accept(resizedImage)
        }
    }
}

This is CustomPostClusterRenderer.swift
class CustomPostClusterRenderer: GMUDefaultClusterRenderer {
    private let GMUAnimationDuration: Double = 0.2
    private weak var mapView: GMSMapView?
    
    override init(mapView: GMSMapView, clusterIconGenerator iconGenerator: GMUClusterIconGenerator) {
        super.init(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        self.mapView = mapView
        self.animationDuration = GMUAnimationDuration
    }
    
    override func shouldRender(as cluster: GMUCluster, atZoom zoom: Float) -> Bool {
        return cluster.count >= 1
    }
}

This is MapPostClusterIconGenerator.swift:
class MapPostClusterIconGenerator: GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator {
    override func icon(forSize size: UInt) -> UIImage {
        return generateIcon(forSize: size)
    }

    private func generateIcon(forSize size: UInt) -> UIImage {
        let iconImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "google-icon")
        let text = String(size) as NSString
        let font = UIFont.Spontivly.Khula.extraBold(16.0)
        return createIconImage(withText: text, baseImage: iconImage, font: font) ?? iconImage
    }
    
    private func createIconImage(withText text: NSString, baseImage: UIImage, font: UIFont) -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(baseImage.size, false, 0.0)
        defer { UIGraphicsEndImageContext() }
        baseImage.draw(in: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: baseImage.size))
        let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
        textStyle.alignment = .center
        let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .font: font,
            .paragraphStyle: textStyle,
            .foregroundColor: UIColor.white
        ]
        let textHeight = font.lineHeight
        let textY = (baseImage.size.height - textHeight) / 2
        let textRect = CGRect(x: 10, y: textY, width: baseImage.size.width - 20, height: textHeight)
        text.draw(in: textRect.integral, withAttributes: attributes)
        return UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    }
}

This is ClusterMarkerView.swift:
class ClusterMarkerView: LoadableView {
    @IBOutlet weak var iconView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var number: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberContainer: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberContainerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    private var url: URL?
    private let disposeBag: DisposeBag = .init()
    
    func update(number: UInt, ratio: CGFloat, uiImage: BehaviorRelay<UIImage?>?) {
        if let uiImage = uiImage {
            uiImage.asDriver().drive(iconView.rx.image).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        } else {
            self.iconView.sd_cancelCurrentImageLoad()
            loadImage(ratio)
        }
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.numberContainer.isHidden = number == 1
            self.numberContainerConstraint.constant = number == 1 ? 0.0 : 11.0
            self.number.text = String(number)
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
    
    private func loadImage(_ ratio: CGFloat) {
        guard let url = url else { return }
        iconView.sd_setImage(with: url,
                             placeholderImage: nil,
                             options: [.continueInBackground, .scaleDownLargeImages],
                             context: [.imagePreserveAspectRatio : false,
                                       .imageThumbnailPixelSize : CGSize(width: 100, height: (100.0 * ratio))],
                             progress: nil) { image, error, cacheType, url in
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading image: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
}

This is MapViewController.swift delegates:
class MapViewController: UIViewController, NonReusableViewProtocol {
    private var mapView: GMSMapView!
    private var alreadyLoadedPosts: Bool = false
    private var isRenderingCluster: Bool = false
    private var postMarkers = [String: MarkerPostItem]()
    private var renderedPostIds = Set<String>()
    private var renderWorkItem: DispatchWorkItem?
    private var isMapMoving = false
    
    let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
    var clusterImage: PFFileObject?
    var clusterItemCount: UInt = 0
    var firstLoad: Bool = true
    var filterISOpened: Bool = false
    var searchOpened: Bool = false
    var ratio: CGFloat = 0.0
    var clusterUiImage: BehaviorRelay<UIImage?>?
    var postClusterManager: GMUClusterManager?
    var subscriptionChecker = Injected<SubscriptionCheckServiceProtocol>()
    
    lazy private var currentLocationMarker: GMSMarker = {
        let currentLocationMarker = GMSMarker()
        currentLocationMarker.map = mapView
        currentLocationMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "user_pin_icon")
        return currentLocationMarker
    }()
    
    lazy var renderer: CustomPostClusterRenderer = {
        let iconGenerator = MapPostClusterIconGenerator()
        let renderer = CustomPostClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView, clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
        renderer.delegate = self
        return renderer
    }()

    private func configurePostMarkerCluster() {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.postClusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: self.mapView, algorithm: self.algorithm, renderer: self.renderer)
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.postClusterManager?.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
                self.postClusterManager?.cluster()
            }
        }
    }

    private func handleFilteredPosts(_ posts: [PhotoPost]) {
        guard !posts.isEmpty else { return }

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            // Set of post IDs in the current filter results
            let currentPostIds = Set(posts.compactMap { $0.objectId })
            
            // Identify markers to remove (those not in the current filter results)
            let postsToRemove = self.renderedPostIds.subtracting(currentPostIds)
            postsToRemove.forEach { postId in
                if let marker = self.postMarkers[postId] {
                    self.postClusterManager?.remove(marker)
                    self.postMarkers.removeValue(forKey: postId)
                }
            }

            // Update `renderedPostIds` to match the current filter
            self.renderedPostIds = currentPostIds
            
            // Identify new posts to add (those in `currentPostIds` but not yet rendered)
            let newPosts = posts.filter { post in
                guard let postId = post.objectId else { return false }
                return !self.postMarkers.keys.contains(postId)
            }
            
            // Sort and add new markers for these posts
            let sortedPosts = newPosts.sorted { ($0.createdAt ?? Date()) > ($1.createdAt ?? Date()) }
            sortedPosts.forEach { post in
                guard let postId = post.objectId else { return }
                let lat = post.location?.latitude ?? 0
                let lng = post.location?.longitude ?? 0
                let marker = MarkerPostItem(position: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat, longitude: lng), post: post, image: post.photoLow)
                
                self.postMarkers[postId] = marker
                self.postClusterManager?.add(marker)
            }

            // Cluster on the main thread after updating markers
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.batchCluster()
            }
        }
    }

    private func updateLocation(_ location: CLLocation) {
        mapView.animate(toLocation: location.coordinate)
    }
    
    private func updateMapPosition(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        mapView.animate(toLocation: coordinate)
    }
}

// MARK: - Delegates
extension MapViewController: GMUClusterRendererDelegate, GMUClusterManagerDelegate, GMSMapViewDelegate {
    
    func clusterManager(_ clusterManager: GMUClusterManager, didTap cluster: GMUCluster) -> Bool {
        closeOpenPanelsIfNeeded()
        
        if let items = cluster.items as? [MarkerPostItem] {
            viewModel?.selectedCluster.publish(items)
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, markerFor object: Any) -> GMSMarker? {
        guard let cluster = object as? GMUStaticCluster,
              let postMarker = cluster.items.first as? MarkerPostItem else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return createMarker(for: cluster, with: postMarker)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, willRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        scheduleClusterRenderReset(marker)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: GMUClusterRenderer, didRenderMarker marker: GMSMarker) {
        finalizeClusterRendering()
    }
    
    func mapViewDidFinishTileRendering(_ mapView: GMSMapView) {
        guard !alreadyLoadedPosts else { return }
        alreadyLoadedPosts = true
        viewModel?.loadPostsMap()
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didChange position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        isMapMoving = true
        debounceMapClusterUpdate(for: position)
    }
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, idleAt position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        isMapMoving = false
        batchCluster() // Trigger clustering when movement stops
    }
}

// MARK: - Private Helper Methods
private extension MapViewController {
    
    /// Close open UI panels such as search or filter
    func closeOpenPanelsIfNeeded() {
        if searchOpened { closeSearchButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) }
        if filterISOpened { filterButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside) }
    }
    
    /// Create and configure a marker for the given cluster and post item
    func createMarker(for cluster: GMUStaticCluster, with postMarker: MarkerPostItem) -> GMSMarker? {
        let marker = GMSMarker()
        let view = ClusterMarkerView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 80, height: 103))
        view.update(number: cluster.count, ratio: postMarker.post.imageRatio, uiImage: postMarker.uiImage)
        marker.iconView = view
        marker.groundAnchor = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1)
        return marker
    }
    
    /// Schedule a reset for cluster rendering status
    func scheduleClusterRenderReset(_ marker: GMSMarker) {
        isRenderingCluster = true
        renderWorkItem?.cancel()
        
        renderWorkItem = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.isRenderingCluster = false
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: renderWorkItem!)
    }
    
    /// Finalize cluster rendering by hiding loading indicators
    func finalizeClusterRendering() {
        isRenderingCluster = false
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
            if !self.isRenderingCluster, self.alreadyLoadedPosts {
                self.loadingView.isHidden = true
                self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
                self.loadingOverlayView.isHidden = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    /// Debounce map clustering updates to avoid frequent recalculations
    func debounceMapClusterUpdate(for position: GMSCameraPosition) {
        let significantZoomChange = abs(mapView.camera.zoom - position.zoom) >= 1.0
        if significantZoomChange {
            batchCluster()
        }
    }

    private func batchCluster() {
        // Clusters markers only if map is not currently moving
        guard !isMapMoving else { return }
        postClusterManager?.cluster()
    }
}

